# should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot()

Tags: laravel

I'm learning Laravel but the tutorial I'm following is using Laravel 5.3 and I'm using latest laravel . the code below always throws this error ErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 8:
Declaration of App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route $router) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot().
please can anyone show me how to rewrite this cold to stope it from throwing this error. thanks in advance

```php
public function boot(Router $router)
{   
    parent::boot($router);
    
    $router -> bind('post', function($slug){
        return Post::published()->where('slug',$slug)->first();
    });
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to type hint dependency in the boot method thereby altering the method signature - hence the error

Try

```php
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; - at the top;
public function boot() {
    Route::bind('post', function ($slug) {
        return App\Models\Post::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    });
}
```

Read more at Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#explicit-binding

Comment: Thank so much for your respond, I tried the code but it didn't work and I got this error: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: Pls give more detail for which route did you get the error and how you are trying to access the route -

Comment: I want to call a slug from the database to create a user-friendly URL for SEO. here  is my route Route::get('/blog/{post}', [
    'uses' => 'BlogController@show',
    'as'   => 'blog.show'
]);

Comment: public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view("blog.show", compact('post'));
    } this is the controller . please help . thank you in advance

Comment: If you try to visit a url ` /blog/{sulg-of-an-existing-db-record}`  - are you getting route not found error

Comment: yes I get that error. in fact, the home page won't even load because of that error

Comment: Can you post your routes file. Also try to `php artisan route:list` and see the output

Comment: 1. for the route file.
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hEhQlGnnxtjJiKfTHdyo9P2SyJYiFZK_/view?usp=sharing  2. for the controller . https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hEhQlGnnxtjJiKfTHdyo9P2SyJYiFZK_/view?usp=sharing Thank you

Comment: when I ran php artisan route:list  it says  c:\xampp\htdocs\Sites\myproject>php artisan route:list
Your application doesn't have any routes.

Comment: I can't access the file on your google drive. Pls post/include the code of the files in your question as code - wrapping between code fence ```

Comment: Thank you so much ! the code is working now